# Efficient way to get twitter followers of multiple accounts (e.g. 5) in a single request?

Tags: twitter, twitter-oauth

Here is a sample query which returns the twitter ids of followers of examplename:

```
https://api.twitter.com/1/followers/ids.json?cursor=-1&screen_name=examplename
```

This works great. However I would like to get followers of up to 5 different twitter accounts. This would mean 5 api calls which is inefficient and not good because I don't want to exceed the api limit. So is there a way to combine 5 different queries into 1?

This web application I am building could potentially be used by 100 simultaneous users at once, according to my employer. Would using authentication (oauth codes) increase my rate limit?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a) No, just stick with tihis method.

b) Yes, if you get oAuth credentials of every user you are trying to get details of (they have logged in), then you can sign each API request using their own oauth token/secret and you don't have any concerns about rate limiting. You can make up to 350 requests per hour using each users credentials.

Comment: Thanks. Could you point me in the documentation how to sign the above API request with the oauth token/secret. I am familiar with oauth and have the oauth credentials of my users in my mysql db.

Comment: You should use library for that, if you are using PHP, the best lib is https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth  Making request itself is simple: `$req = new TwitterOAuth($consumer_key, $consumer_secret, $btok, $bsec);  $result = $req->OAuthRequest('http://twitter.com/some_method.xml');`